# "If Not Exists" on Arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs

I want to insert values into an Arango-DB with Custom Keys, but I didn't found a 'if not exists' function like at SQL

```
let exist = (
  FOR u IN User
     FILTER u._key == "newkey"
     return u
  )
Filter LENGTH(exist)==null
    INSERT{
        _key:               "newkey",
         value1:             "value"
     } IN User
return NEW
```

Something like this also doesn't work

```
INSERT{
    _key:               "newkey",
    value1:             "value"
}
IN User ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
return NEW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about looking at the `UPSERT` command, and only give it instructions for the `INSERT` part of the command and nothing for `UPDATE`.  That way it would only execute if it didn't exist.

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/upsert/

Here is an example of it being used:

```
UPSERT {
    username: @username
}
INSERT {
    username: @username,
    fullname: @fullname,
    verified: false
}
UPDATE {
}
IN Users

RETURN {
    user: NEW
}
```

The `UPSERT` command has three sections to it.

The first is the comparitor, it's how it identifies if a document exists or not. In this case the comparitor is `{ username: @username }`. It uses this to search the `Users` collection to see if there is a match or not.

If there IS NOT a match, it performs the `INSERT` command.
If there IS a match, it performs the `UPDATE` command.

In this case we have been tricky and not provided anything for the `UPDATE` command, so it won't update anything if it exists, it will only insert if it doesn't exist.

The `INSERT` block then shows the keys/values that it inserts if the record is not found.

In this case, it is also setting verified to `false` because any new user that has just been created is not verified. It will be the responsibility of another command elsewhere in the app to convert this flag to `true`.

Also notice the `RETURN` entry, it references `NEW` and you can also reference a thing called `OLD` if needed.

These are internal return values provided by an `UPSERT` command and they reference two versions of the document that was referenced.

`NEW` is always populated, it contains the latest version of the document, regardless if an update was made or not.

`OLD` contains the old version of the document, before it was updated with the new values. If the document is not updated then it returns null, so in this case it will always be null as updates don't happen.

And yes, this executes exactly as an `IF NOT EXISTS` style command in other database languages. If the comparator doesn't match, it inserts the new record, if the comparator matches, it does nothing!

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible, that you can create a sample Query. It don't worked for me, without the Options.

Comment: Thank you, my reputatoin is to low, to upvote :) when i can make it, i will do

Answer (score 0):

```
LET existingUser = FIRST(
  FOR u IN User
     FILTER u._key == "newkey"
     return u
)
LET newUser = FIRST(
  FILTER existingUser == null
  INSERT{
        _key:               "newkey",
         value1:             "value"
     } IN User
  RETURN NEW
)
RETURN existingUser || newUser
```

This returns the existing user or inserts a user if it doesn't exist.
The user object is then returned.

There are no unnecessary write operations

Answer (score -1):

its a little bit unsatisfactory, the Arangodb community helped me. It doesn't exist a query like "IF NOT EXITS", the database-system throws in this case an exeption, to make the query usable, you must be add a ignore error-message dialog.

```
INSERT{
    _key:               "key",
    value1:             "value"
}in Users OPTIONS {ignoreErrors: true}
return NEW
```

Comment: This solution is correct, too and depending on the case the only possible